# Is there a way to save another field value (e.g _id) when selecting a value from Picker?

Tags: swiftui, realm, picker

I have these classes - User and Centre

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id = UUID().uuidString
    @Persisted var userName = ""
    @Persisted var firstName = ""
    @Persisted var lastName = ""
    @Persisted var userMobile = ""
    @Persisted var userCentre = ""
    @Persisted var userCentreId: ObjectId?
    @Persisted var userPreferences: UserPreferences?
    @Persisted var lastSeenAt: Date?
    @Persisted var conversations = List<Conversation>()
    @Persisted var presence = "On-Line"

    var isProfileSet: Bool { !(userPreferences?.isEmpty ?? true) }
    var presenceState: Presence {
        get { return Presence(rawValue: presence) ?? .hidden }
        set { presence = newValue.asString }
    }
    
    convenience init(userName: String, id: String) {
        self.init()
        self.userName = userName
        _id = id
        userPreferences = UserPreferences()
        userPreferences?.displayName = userName
        presence = "On-Line"
    }
}

enum Presence: String {
    case onLine = "On-Line"
    case offLine = "Off-Line"
    case hidden = "Hidden"
    
    var asString: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}


import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import MapKit

class Centre: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @Persisted var centreName = ""
    @Persisted var centreDesc = ""
    @Persisted var centreLocation: Coordinates?
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
          return "_id"
      }
  
    convenience init(centreName: String, centreDesc: String, x: Double, y: Double) {
         self.init()
         self.centreName = centreName
         self.centreDesc = centreDesc
         self.centreLocation?.x = x
         self.centreLocation?.y = y
     }
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (centreLocation?.y)!, longitude: (centreLocation?.x)!)
        }
}
```

I have a view to set up user profile and the user's associated centre with a picker showing the available centres. I would like to also save the _id of the centre when the centre name is selected. How do I do that? Is it possible to pass a hidden value in Picker or should I use two Pickers - will take up screen space.

```
struct SetUserProfileView: View {
    @AppStorage("shouldShareLocation") var shouldShareLocation = false
    @Environment(\.realm) var realm
    @ObservedRealmObject var user: User
    @ObservedResults(Centre.self) var centres
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var userID: String?
    
    @State private var displayName = ""
    @State private var photo: Photo?
    @State private var photoAdded = false
    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""
    @State private var userMobile = ""
    @State private var selectedCentre = ""
    @State public var selectedCentreId: ObjectId
    
    var body: some View {
   
        Form {
            Section {
                if let photo = photo {
                    AvatarButton(photo: photo) {
                        self.showPhotoTaker()
                    }
                }
                if photo == nil {
                    Button(action: { self.showPhotoTaker() }) {
                        Text("Add Photo")
                    }
                }
                TextField("Display Name", text: $displayName)
                TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
                TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName)
                TextField( "Mobile Number", text: $userMobile)
                Text("Select Centre")
                Picker(selection: $selectedCentre, label: Text("Select Centre")) {
                    Text("Nothing Selected").tag("")
                    ForEach(centres, id: \.self) { centre in
                        Text(centre.centreName).tag(centre.centreName)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: initData)
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                .accentColor(.white)
```

Comment: Here's an off topic question: this is Realm and Realm has relationships between objects - why are you storing the selectedCentreId (an objectId)? Why not just store the selected center itself? That would make queries and pulling data from the that center much easier (if that's even needed). Where in your code are you reacting to a  center change in the picker?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this

```
Text("Select Centre")
Picker(selection: $selectedCentre, label: Text("Select Centre")) {
    Text("Nothing Selected").tag("")
    ForEach(centres, id: \.self) { centre in
        Text(centre.centreName).tag(centre.centreName)
    }
}
.onChange(of: selectedCentre) { value in
    // do whatever needed here             // << here !!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still can't get the hang of it. I want id of selected centre (centre._id) to be saved to selectedCentreId